# objeto dinámico se cambia cuando modifico otro objeto VUE

Tags: vue.js

Aquí esta el ejemplo de mi problema:
https://jsfiddle.net/m7g1uwL7/30/

si solo cambio el `app.v_total` por que los input pierden sus check que pongo con `v-if`? (creo que es por que VUE cree que `test` también se actualiza) y no debería de ser así.

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo html y las funciones que se usan para tu componente.

Comment: editado* el problema que veo es que si modifico cualquier otro objeto del VUE el 'app.features'' se actualiza aun que no cambie en nada

Comment: agregaste solo una parte con eso no se entiende mucho incluso hay variables o funciones  que ejecutas pero que no se ve que es lo que hacen.

Comment: editado* es por VUE y no se que pasa

Comment: ya encontré tu error pero quiero corrobarlo con una pruebas adicionales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que veo es que si bien al iterar en lo elementos obtienes el  `checked` si cumple o no la función  cuando este valor se cambia no persiste ya que no se guarda en algún model y que al cambiar un valor de tu componente **`Vue`** este se refresca con los datos que persisten por ello no guarda los checks que hagas después. Para solucionar eso añadí al input `v-model="date.check"` que guardaría si esta con check  y que por medio de esa variable deberías controlar si `price==0`.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#mainCreate',
  data: {
    v_total : 0,
    test : [],
  },
});



function f_test(){
  var d = [
    {title : 'p1', price : 0, check: true},
    {title : 'p2', price : 2, check: true},
    {title : 'p3', price : 0, check: true},
    {title : 'p4', price : 4, check: true}
  ]

  $.each(d, function(index,date){
    Vue.set(app.test, index, date);
  });
}

function changeV(){
 app.v_total += 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="mainCreate">
<h4>I input the charge with a check according to a v-if, but look what happens if I select an input that was not checked and change the value of v_total .... reload the input</h4>


    v_total = {{ v_total}}
  <br>
    <span v-for="date in test">
      {{ date.title }}
      <input type="checkbox"
             name="featuresBox"
             v-model="date.check">
      <br>
    </span>

    <button onClick="f_test()">create object</button>
    <button onClick="changeV()">change app.v_total</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias